# Ubuntu One stuck and doing nothing

Tags: ubuntu-one

Ubuntu One has worked fine for me for several weeks and I now have 8.2 GB of files in the clouds. Then, last night, Ubuntu One stopped working. When I fire up `System > Preferences > Ubuntu One`, it tells me that I have 8.2 GB stored (13.2 %) and that my status is *Unknown*.

I've tried to restart to no avail. I even tried to remove, followed by clearing the password keyring and starting over. Still nothing. I've run out of buttons to push.

Comment: can you post any messages that are produced when you run ubuntu one preferences from a terminal. to do this hit ctrl+alt+t on your keyboard then enter ubuntuone-preferences at the prompt and hit enter.

Answer (score 4):

What I do is:

```
u1sdtool -q
find ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon -depth -type d -empty -delete
u1sdtool --start
u1sdtool -c
```

Sometimes I need to do this 5 times.

Also weird is when I push 'connect' nothing happens, but when I do `u1sdtool -c` in terminal, it is starting to connect.

---

I just want to add that since / after upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04 I don't have this problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

I started to ask about this over at [Can I reinstall Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46226/can-i-reinstall-ubuntu-one) but here's what worked for me:

`u1sdtool -q`

Remove `.local/share/ubuntuone`, `Ubuntu One`, `.cache/ubuntuone`, and `.config/ubuntuone`

I also did `ps aux | grep ubuntu` and killed two running processes:

```
amanda    3062  0.1  0.7  45372 23460 ?        SL   07:54   0:19 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-login
amanda    7373 13.6  6.1 402320 189516 ?       Sl   10:27   1:48 /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.17/firefox-bin http://one.ubuntu.com/account
```

Then ...

`u1sdtool --start` followed by `u1sdtool -c`

I had to re-connect my computer to Ubuntu One but it seems to be connected now.