# Can I reinstall Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

UbuntuOne is not working -- [connection issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44944/devices-tab-has-no-connect-option) -- and I've been having trouble with using Funambol and SyncEvolution as a substitute, so I'd like to try to get Ubuntu One working for me.

I tried reinstalling it with Synaptic, I walked through the troubleshooting steps on UbuntuOne. When I open UbuntuOne from the "me" menu, it does appear to connect to my account -- it reports my usage and shows my current plan and devices, but it also says "disconnected"

I tried the fix at:
[Unable to connect to Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31894/unable-to-connect-to-ubuntu-one/38089#38089)

`u1sdtool -s` just sits there -- nothing happens and I don't get a new command prompt.

`u1sdtool -q` does report `ubuntuone-syncdaemon stopped.`

I removed my computer from the list, removed `.cache/ubuntuone` `.config/ubuntuone` and `~/Ubuntu One` and tried to connect again. Now I'm getting a status response at least:

```
[0 amanda@luna ~]$ u1sdtool -s
State: READY
    connection: Not User Not Network
    description: ready to connect
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: IDLE
```

So I tried *again* -- did `u1sdtool -q`  and this time there was also a `.local/share/ubuntuone` directory to remove, along with `Ubuntu One` and the `ubuntuone` directories in .cache and .config. I also did `ps aux | grep ubuntu` and killed two running processes:

```
amanda    3062  0.1  0.7  45372 23460 ?        SL   07:54   0:19 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-login
amanda    7373 13.6  6.1 402320 189516 ?       Sl   10:27   1:48 /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.17/firefox-bin http://one.ubuntu.com/account
```

Then I `u1sdtool --start` followed by `u1sdtool -c` and Firefox did open the "connect this computer" dialog, which seems to have worked. So I seem to be connected. But man, oh man was that a pill.

Any idea how I should have gone about this to begin with?

Comment: Of course, I'm on 10.04 so this was all pretty much for naught since all I really want to sync is my contacts. Argh. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentMyContactsInEvolutionSyncing

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards